# WPF - Passing parameter from Dialog Window to UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, dependency-properties

I'm using DependencyProperty to pass parameters from DialogWindow to UserControl.
I want that parameter inside the UserControl constructor in order to pass it to the view model.

The property always returns null, and never get set.

Code:

MainWindow:

```
var dialog = new DialogWindow();
dialog.ShowDialog();
```

DialogWindow.xaml

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Data Source">
        <local:DataSourceView Test="Something" />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

DataSourceView.xaml.cs

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Test", typeof(object), typeof(DataSourceView));
public object Test {
    get { return (object)GetValue(TestProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TestProperty, value); }
}
public DataSourceView() {
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new DataSourceViewModel(Test);// Test is always null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use overload of `DependencyProperty.Register` method with `PropertyMetadata` which will have a `PropertyChangedCallback` parameter and observe data binding process.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Test", typeof(object), typeof(DataSourceView), new PropertyMetadata(TestPropertyChangedCallback
    ));

    private static void TestPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.NewValue);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.OldValue);
    }
```

Following link contains the solution for a similar problem:

[Passing Parameters between xaml window and usercontrol WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21717600/passing-parameters-between-xaml-window-and-usercontrol-wpf?rq=1)

Comment: There is a similar situation in here:

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21717600/passing-parameters-between-xaml-window-and-usercontrol-wpf?rq=1)

You should move your setting of DataContext to Loaded event handler.

Comment: Using the call back method I've found that the property gets set after the View instance is done, and using the link you have provided in the comment, I now have access to the right value. could you please update your answer to contain the link in your comment. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

"The property always returns null, and never get set." - Is wrong. The property is null in DataSourceView constructor. After the instance of DataSourceView is created, property will be set to "Something".

Comment: Yes, you're right, I have noticed that using the call back method which have been suggested in madiden's answer. thanks for your answer :)